# AssertionError during test without clear error message

Tags: python

this is probably something really simple.

I have written this class

```
class Pants :
    def __init__(self, pants_color, waist_size, length, price):
        self.color = pants_color
        self.waist_size = waist_size
        self.length = length
        self.price = price

    def change_price(self, new_price):
        self.price = new_price

    def discount(self, discount):
        self.price = self.price * (1 - discount)
```

and I am running these tests on it:

```
def check_results():
    pants = Pants('red', 35, 36, 15.12)
    assert pants.color == 'red'
    assert pants.waist_size == 35
    assert pants.length == 36
    assert pants.price == 15.12

    pants.change_price(10) == 10
    assert pants.price == 10 

    assert pants.discount(.1) == 9

    print('You made it to the end of the check. Nice job!')

check_results()
```

For some reason I keep seeing an error Message without an actual error, it just says AssertionError:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-50abebbadc01> in <module>()
     13     print('You made it to the end of the check. Nice job!')
     14 
---> 15 check_results()

<ipython-input-5-50abebbadc01> in check_results()
      9     assert pants.price == 10
     10 
---> 11     assert pants.discount(.1) == 9
     12 
     13     print('You made it to the end of the check. Nice job!')

AssertionError:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`assert` will only print the error message you give, for example:

```
assert pants.discount(.1) == 9, "Pants discount should be {}, was {}".format(9, pants.discount(0.1))
```

will give the error

```
AssertionError: Pants discount should be 9, was None
```

It is recommended to put a message for every assert statement. Alternatively, you can use inherit from `UnitTest` from the `unittest` module, and use the speciality `assertEquals` method, which has built-in pretty error printing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes apparently I had to add a `return` instead of just setting the new price.
I'll share this none the less in case anotherone encouters it

```
 def discount(self, discount):
    return self.price * (1 - discount)
```

Comment: It might make more sense to call `pants.discount` and then assert the `self.price` has the expected value.  Returning the value just to make the test work is wasteful and violates command/query separation.